# File Transfer - Packet Rounds

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock, packet

I'm basically using a 20,480byte buffer that is into a packet structure. Here is the structure:

```
struct PACKET
{
    DWORD Header;
    char data[20480];
    bool eof;
};
```

What I'm doing is reading a file 20,480bytes at a time and sending it until all the file has been sent. I am testing this on a 3MB file and roughly 150 rounds are sent.

Here is the code:

```
PACKET sc;
sc.Header = 0xB;
ifstream file("test.pdf", ios::ate | ios::binary | ios::in);
    DWORD fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg)

    int counter = 20480;
    int rounds = fileSize / 20480 + 1;
```

And the sending loop:

```
while (rounds != 0)
{
    sc.eof = false;

    file.read(sc.data, sizeof(sc.data));

    send(Slick.client, (char*)&sc, sizeof(sc), 0);

    file.seekg(counter + 1);
    counter = counter + 20480;

    rounds--;
    Sleep(1);

       if (rounds == 0) sc.eof = true;

    cout << "Left to send: " << rounds << endl;
}
file.close();
cout << "All data was sent!" << endl;
```

I'm using asynchronous sockets on the other side, so my problem is that sometimes it receives 140 packets, sometimes 130, 147, 148 etc and the file is always corrupted. What am I doing wrong?

---

Here is the other side:

```
case PACKET_FILE:
                    {
                        if (isOpen == false)
                        {
                            isOpen = true;
                            file.open("tester.pdf", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::app);
                            file.write(pack.data, sizeof(pack.data));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pack.eof == true)
                            {

                                file.write(pack.data, sizeof(pack.data));
                                file.close();
                                MessageBox(NULL, "File Received", "LOL", MB_OK);
                                break;
                            }
                                file.write(pack.data, sizeof(pack.data));
                        }
                        countz++;
                        char bue[10];
                        itoa(countz, bue, 10);
                        SendMessage(hlabelPackets, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)(bue));
                        break;
                    }
```

Please help, it makes no sense...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem lies in the setup of the socket. If you use UDP you will not have guarantee of delivery and they will not neccesarily arrive in the same order you sent them.

Also, it seems like you always send 20480 bytes even though the end of the file is reached. This can cause the file on the receiving side to have garbage at the end.